# Java generics - clarification

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics

I have an interface.

```
public interface PaymentXmlObject {

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class MonthPaymentXml implements PaymentXmlObject {
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class QuarterPaymentXml implements PaymentXmlObject {
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class YearPaymentXml implements PaymentXmlObject {
}
```

Processor class,

```
public abstract class PaymentXmlProcessor<T extends PaymentXmlObject> { 
  public abstract Mono<Void> processXmlObject(final T xmlObject);
}

public class MonthPaymentXmlProcessor extends PaymentXmlProcessor<MonthPaymentXml> {
   @Override
    public Mono<Void> processXmlObject(final MonthPaymentXml monthObject) {
     ...
    }
}

public class QuarterPaymentXmlProcessor extends PaymentXmlProcessor<QuarterPaymentXml> {
   @Override
    public Mono<Void> processXmlObject(final QuarterPaymentXml monthObject) {
     ...
    }
}

public class YearPaymentXmlProcessor extends PaymentXmlProcessor<YearPaymentXml> {
   @Override
    public Mono<Void> processXmlObject(final YearPaymentXml monthObject) {
     ...
    }
}
```

Factory class,

```
public class PaymentXmlProcessorFactory {

    private final PaymentXmlProcessor<MonthPaymentXml> monthXmlProcessor;
    private final PaymentXmlProcessor<QuarterPaymentXml> quarterXmlProcessor;
    private final PaymentXmlProcessor<YearPaymentXml> yearXmlProcessor;

    @Inject
    public FinrefXmlProcessorFactory(final PaymentXmlProcessor<MonthPaymentXml> monthXmlProcessor,
                                     final PaymentXmlProcessor<QuarterPaymentXml> quarterXmlProcessor,
                                     final PaymentXmlProcessor<YearPaymentXml> yearXmlProcessor) {
        this.monthXmlProcessor = monthXmlProcessor;
        this.quarterXmlProcessor = quarterXmlProcessor;
        this.yearXmlProcessor = yearXmlProcessor;
    }

    public PaymentXmlProcessor<?> getXmlProcessorByType(String paymentType) {
        switch (paymentType) {
            case "MONTH":
                return monthXmlProcessor;
            case "QUARTER":
                return quarterXmlProcessor;
            case "YEAR":
                return yearXmlProcessor;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid payment type: " + paymentType);
        }
    }
}
```

In my main class,

```
private Mono<Void> processXmlObject(String paymentType, PaymentXmlObject xmlObject) {
        PaymentXmlProcessor<? extends PaymentXmlObject> xmlProcessor = processorFactory.getXmlProcessorByType(paymentType);
        return xmlProcessor.processXmlObject(xmlObject);
    }
```

Here the call to the method processXmlObject gives me the error below.

> The method processXmlObject(capture#2-of ? extends PaymentXmlObject) in
> the type PaymentXmlProcessor<capture#2-of ? extends PaymentXmlObject> is
> not applicable for the arguments  (PaymentXmlObject)

What is the best way to go with a generic approach?

**Approach 2:-**

```
public class PaymentXmlProcessorFactory implements {
    private final Map<Class<? extends PaymentXmlObject>, PaymentXmlProcessor<?>> processorRegistry;

    @Inject
    public PaymentXmlProcessorFactory(final MessageBuilder messageBuilder, final DataManager dataManager,
                                            final Properties properties) {
        processorRegistry = new HashMap<>();
        processorRegistry.put(FiscalMonthPayloadXml.class, new FiscalMonthXmlProcessor(messageBuilder, dataManager, properties));
        processorRegistry.put(FiscalQuarterPayloadXml.class, new FiscalQuarterXmlProcessor(messageBuilder, dataManager, properties));
        processorRegistry.put(FiscalYearPayloadXml.class, new FiscalYearXmlProcessor(messageBuilder, dataManager, properties));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T extends PaymentXmlObject> PaymentXmlProcessor<T> getXmlProcessor(Class<? extends T> objectType) {
        return (PaymentXmlProcessor<T>) processorRegistry.get(objectType);
    }
}
```

From the main class,

```
public Mono<Void> processXmlObject(final PaymentXmlObject xmlObject) {
        PaymentXmlProcessor<PaymentXmlObject> processor = processorFactory1.getXmlProcessor(xmlObject.getClass());
        processor.processXmlObject(xmlObject);
    }
```

The 2nd approach is not showing any error. is this correct?

Comment: You could fix the error like this: `var xmlProcessor = (PaymentXmlProcessor<? super PaymentXmlObject>) processorFactory.getXmlProcessorByType(paymentType);` but there's no way to verify the type is correct.

Comment: What is the best approach? Now the error is at the next line.
The method processXmlObject(capture#2-of ?) in the type PaymentXmlProcessor<capture#2-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments 
(PaymentXmlObject)

Comment: Are you sure you used `super` and not `extends` in the wildcard?

Comment: I used extends not super.

Comment: That's the issue then; it should be `super`.

Comment: Can you point where exactly?

Comment: Because `? extends PaymentXmlObject` could be a subclass of `PaymentXmlObject` and you cannot pass a value of type `PaymentXmlObject` to a parameter that accepts a subtype of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254317/discussion-between-user1578872-and-unmitigated).